# How can I restore a database in SQL Server 2012 from SQL Server 2012 Express?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I am having problems to restore a database from SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Express to my SQL Server 2012 where I need this db to do some tests.

When I select the `.bak` file it is nothing shown in the 'backup sets to restore' area below. This is the newest backup I have made.

Is there any way to make it happen? even settings that I must have to do?

I have read that there is impossible to restore from the a higher SQL Server version? Is that true?

Best Regards,

Weslley.

Comment: The original post referred to SQL Server 2012R2. This was corrected to SQL Server 2012. Is this correct or were you referring to SQL Server 2008 R2? Why are you referring to a higher SQL Server version ? In the current post both databases are 2012 versions.

Comment: @JacodeGroot: there is no **2012 R2** version - therefore I fixed it to **2012** (assuming the OP probably meant **2012 SP2**)

Comment: Hi, 
so i was asking that because I was trying to restore a database to two others environments, and one of them were SQL Server 2008R2.

I read that i cannot make a restore from a Higher SQL Version.. I was just making sure about that information I have read.
Thanks very much Anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks very much for the help you gave.

I did not know that when I go to the button Help/About I was seeing the version of the SSMS and not of the DataBase..

So in both case i was trying to restore a database from a higher version, so it could not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

What do you see (if anything) when you run this command:

```
USE [master]

RESTORE HEADERONLY 
FROM DISK = N'your-drive-and-path-to-the-backup-file.bak' 
WITH NOUNLOAD;
GO
```

Does that show you anything? Does it cause an error? If so: *what* error?